# Blob Storage vs Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-media-services

I'm using blob storage to serve uploaded user posted videos in a xamarin application, but the performance is terrible.  Can Azure media services serve these videos with good performance?

Comment: Are the users uploading just standard MP4 files and you are progressive downloading them?  If you are seeing buffering or slow stalled playback then it’s likely the files are too high bitrate for the bandwidth. You would benefit from adaptive bitrate encoding and delivery in AMS. Also if the content is hot and widely viewed you may need CDN enabled to cache it closer to viewers.

Comment: "Terrible" is subjective; we don't have any details here, as you haven't provided any (you can edit your question to be specific). We also don't know what type of storage account you created; we don't know if you're providing direct links to content or if you're trying to stream them through, say, a web app (which has different bandwidth limitations). Unfortunately, as written, there's simply no way to provide an answer. Also note that Azure Storage and Media Services are completely different services with very different pricing models. They are not interchangeable services.

Comment: Also: aside from the performance concerns: we really can't recommend one service over another; we don't know your specific feature needs, budget, etc. Tool/product/service recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, yes I know my question is vague and I'd probably get dinged for it.  I'm simply uploading videos from a phone, saving them to hot blob storage.  Trying to play them back with a SAS link straight from blob storage.  In iOS it works ok.  In Android, the 'poor' performance is as follows:  a 30 second video takes over a minute to load, if at all.  I've read numerous posts about Xamarin video players for Android, and even tried a webview with html5.  The webview shows a player but its blank. I know this is getting off topic

Answer (score 0):

Try one of our quick starts for encoding and streaming and see if you get better performance for your scenario.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/

There are some threads on using adaptive streaming in Xamarin as well.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to the Xamarin adaptive streaming?  The pricing for AMS is very confusing.

Comment: I’ll have to search forum posts. What confused you on pricing page? Always looking for improvements